# Iterate Over List of Jobs to Print Position, Name, Employer, Position, and Core Competency

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary

I have a method in my `Program.cs` file that I'm trying to implement. When the method iterates over a List of jobs (where each job is a Dictionary) it should print:

```
*****
name: Data Scientist / Business Intelligence
employer: Bull Moose Industries
location: Saint Louis
position type: Sr. IT Analyst (Data/BI)    
core competency: Statistical Analysis
*****
```

The file `job_data.csv` contains the all of the job information that I need:

```
name,employer,location,position type,core competency
Junior Data Analyst,Lockerdome,Saint Louis,Data Scientist / Business Intelligence,Statistical Analysis
Project Coordinator Support,Maritz,Saint Louis,Technical Assistant / User Support,Non-coding
Junior Web Developer,Cozy,Portland,Web - Front End,Ruby
Junior Developer 3,LiveAnswer,South Florida,Web - Full Stack,Java
Full Stack Engineer,Splitwise,Rhode Island,Web - Full Stack,Ruby
Customer Experience,Splitwise,Rhode Island,Project Manager / Analyst,Non-coding
IT Support Specialist,Viamontech,South Florida,Technical Assistant / User Support,Non-coding
C#/.net Developer ,Hunter Engineering,Saint Louis,Software / Enterprise Developer,.Net
Junior Developer,"TruckMovers.com, Inc.",Kansas City,Web - Full Stack,Python
```

...and so on (there are 99 lines total). What I need to do is to write the `PrintJobs` method so that it reaches into `job_data.csv` and prints out the labels:

```
name: 
employer:
location:
position type:
core competency:
```

followed by their corresponding items in each row. So printing line 10, for example, would look like this:

```
*****
name: Junior Developer
employer: "TruckMovers.com, Inc."
location: Kansas City
positon type: Web - Full Stack
core competency: Python
*****
```

How can I do this? The starter code for the method is:

```
private static void PrintJobs(List<Dictionary<string, string>> someJobs)
{
        Console.WriteLine("printJobs is not implemented yet");
}
```

I'm not entirely sure where the parameter `someJobs` comes from. Also here is the hint I was given:

To do this, you'll need to iterate over a List of jobs. Each job is itself a Dictionary. While you can get each of the items out of the dictionary using the known keys ("employer", "location", etc), think instead about creating a nested loop to loop over each dictionary. You'll want to use the Dictionary.Keys property to do this. If a new field is added to the job records, this approach will print out the new field without any updates to PrintJobs.

Based on the hint I would guess that I need to do something like:

```
private static void PrintJobs(List<Dictionary<string, string>> someJobs)
    {

    //match up index value with label, write label + value 

    if (i = [0])
        {Console.WriteLine("name: "); + string someJobs}

    else if (i = [1])
        {Console.WriteLine("employer: "); + string someJobs}

    else if (i = [2])
        {Console.WriteLine("location: "); + string someJobs}

    else if (i = [3])
        {Console.WriteLine("positon type: "); + string someJobs}

    else if (i = [4])
        {Console.WriteLine("core competencey: "); + string someJobs}

    }
```

I tried this and still get the message:

```
printJobs is not implemented yet
```

Complete beginner at C#.
Links to full code:

[Program.cs](http://pastebin.com/yMC54jT2), [JobData.cs](http://pastebin.com/RzEg0KTV), [job_data.csv](http://pastebin.com/Ft8JecFN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work that I originally thought I needed to do was already done for me in the main method in Program.cs. As far as why I was still getting the message: `printJobs is not implemented yet`, C# compiles and runs the last working version of your code if it finds any build errors. Since my code had several build errors, it was running the latest version before I made any changes. Also I needed to restart the module (x - out) before I saved and ran my project again.

As far as implementing PrintJobs, I needed to create a nested foreach loop. The first foreach reaches into the strings in `Dictionary`, which are in the list `someJobs`, and the second foreach reaches into the string `pair`, which is stored in `item`. The program automatically knows that `someJobs` is a list because it's declared just before it.

```
private static void PrintJobs(List<Dictionary<string, string>> someJobs)
    {
        foreach(Dictionary<string,string> item in someJobs)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in item) {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
            }
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("printJobs is not implemented yet");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen your full code but as far as I understand your question, you want to print data of your csv as you mentioned in the following part

```
*****
name: Junior Developer
employer: "TruckMovers.com, Inc."
location: Kansas City
positon type: Web - Full Stack
core competency: Python
*****
```

You can achieve this by using `LINQ` very easily by doing something like this:

```
  var result = File.ReadAllLines(csvPath)
               .Skip(1)//skipping first line because they are headers
               .Select(x => x.Split(','))
               .Select(x => new
               {
                   Name = x[0],
                   employer = x[1],
                   location = x[2],
                   position_type = x[3],
                   core_competency = x[4]
               });
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Name+"\n");
            //...
            Console.WriteLine("Position Type: " + item.position_type);
        }
```

The code will print data as you want them. Let me know if you want something else.

This is a tested code and it works.

Comment: No what you did was already done for me in JobData.cs. All I need to do is create a nested loop that loops through the dictionary and prints out the results. This is what I don't know how to do. 

I'm guessing it's going to be something like: for (int item in Dictionary.Keys) {
Console.WriteLine("columnChoice" + "columnItem");

Comment: It needs to be a nested for loop by the way, so something like: for (Dictionary in someJobs) {
    for (i in someJobs) {
        Console.WriteLine(ColumnChoice + string value);
    }
}

And I need to define the name and type of Dictionary